# Odd behavior with query using DBLink

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is will be difficult to reproduce.

A query with this pattern

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT
  JOIN table2@myLink t2
    ON t1.key_field = t2.key_field
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT a.*,
               3 dummyField
          FROM table3@myLink a
       ) t3
    ON T1.key_key = t3.key_Field
   AND t3.dummyfield = 
         ( SELECT 3
             FROM dual
         );
```

Fails with this error

```
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
01799. 00000 -  "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"
*Cause:    <expression>(+) <relop> (<subquery>) is not allowed.
*Action:   Either remove the (+) or make a view out of the subquery.
           In V6 and before, the (+) was just ignored in this case.
```

Here's where it gets weird, this pattern works just fine:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2@myLink) t2 -- Note trivial subquery wrapper
    ON t1.key_field = t2.key_field
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT a.*,
               3 dummyField
          FROM table3@myLink a
       ) t3
    ON T1.key_key = t3.key_Field
   AND t3.dummyfield = 
         ( SELECT 3
             FROM dual
         );
```

Any thoughts? What on earth is happening here?

Also, I have these tables in the same schema in a different environment and the first query runs without error without the db links.

Comment: I believe that both of your queries are eranomous. Second Left join on both queries have incorrect syntax (LEFT JOIN ON ... )

Comment: @Simonare erroneous*.  That was a typo, these aren't the actual queries that I'm running, just patterns to show that the trivial subquery on "dual" somehow makes a difference. The actual queries being run are both syntactically correct.

Comment: @Error_2646 * Trivial subquery on the second join.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at the execution plans for both queries, in both the environments, to see differences in how the optimiser is approaching them.

Answer (score 0):

the problem arises on the last condition where the left side operand is column whether right side operand is subquery for the outer joined query :

```
AND t3.dummyfield = ( SELECT 3 FROM dual );
```

if you change this part as :

```
WHERE t3.dummyfield =  ( SELECT 3 FROM dual );
```

your problem will be resolved.

your working query will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2@myLink t2
  ON t1.key_field = t2.key_field
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT a.*,3 dummyField
    FROM table3@myLink a) t3 
ON  T1.key_key = t3.key_Field
WHERE t3.dummyfield = ( SELECT 3
  FROM dual
);
```

PS: please note that both of your queries has syntax error on the second LEFT JOIN ON operand.
PS: please note that your second query does not work as well with the `JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2@myLink) t2`

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from Oracle Support Doc ID 2258768.1

We do not support outer joining a column to a subquery and hence ORA-1799 is expected behavior.

However ORA-1799 incorrectly gets avoided due to query transformation when query refers local object.